# Weird behavior with foreign keys and relations in ERD software, is this how SQL works?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been tasked with creating a database but first i have to create a design of it as an erd, i am using for this a program named toad data modeler, but i have one problem with the foreign keys and relations in general.

As seen by this picture(the database is in Polish but you should understand what i mean) :

https://i.ibb.co/Qj6r7Dk/436343664.jpg

The row id_pacjenta shows up in entity9 without a reason, i didn't create a relation between pacjenci and entity9, only entity 9 and Wizyta, Why such a behavior occurs? Also i can't delete it because it automatically deletes also the row that i need (id_wizyty) What i suppose happen is that it takes that row that i don't want (id_pacjenta) from the relationship that i made between Pacjenci and Wizyta, but i don't know why and if it should work that way, what steps should i take to fix this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Nope - it shows up for a reason. Entity9 (really - you need to give your entities and relationships good, useful, helpful names) is an intersection table used to manage a M:M relationship between Choroby and Wizyta. Therefore, it requires the columns of the primary key of each table.

Comment: Thank you, hovewer id_pacjenta in wizyta isn't a primary key (unless i don't know what a primary key is which is also possible), its a foreign key referencing id_pacjenta from another table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing weird about it.

`entity9` references `wizyta` and the primary key of `wizyta` includes a column `id_pacjenta`, so of course there has to be a corresponding column for `wizyta.id_pacjenta` in `entity9`, which is part of the foreign key referencing `wizyta`.

So the tool is correct to add both columns, when you introduce a relationship between the tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot but does that mean that when i want to actually add something to that Entity9 i have to specify also id_pacjenta? Seems kinda counterintuitive to be honest cause entity9 is a bridge between completly different tables than pacjenci.

Comment: Yes. And there is nothing counter intuitive about that. The **pair** `id_wizyty` and `id_pacjenta` is the key and that's something different than `id_pacjenta` alone.

Comment: Thank you so much, i am starting to get it, hovewer before i was trying out things for a bit to "fix" (as i thought it was wrong) this and when i used non-identifying relationships the erd looked like i actually wanted but i don't know, is this good?

https://i.ibb.co/xMYMC1G/124141244.jpg

Comment: @Flamyngo: The question you should ask yourself is: Does `id_pacjenta` have to be in the primary key of `vizyta`. If it hasn't remove it from the primary key and it will be no longer needed in foreign keys referencing `vizyty`.

Comment: I think i understand all of it now, even tho id_pacjenta is required for wizyty i don't want to delete the row that has for example id_pacjenta 1 if i delete a row from pacjenci with that id, so i am now using non-identifiying relationships, and its all looking how its supposed to look did i get it right this time? Thank you for you help again, you SQL angel you.